# Add a setting to choose the default list

Tags: feature-request, saves

When I open the Saves tab I always get displayed **all** of my saved posts even though I have organized them in a few lists. It would be nice to have a setting where I can choose which list is displayed as the default when I open the Saves tab. If that's not feasible I'd prefer "For later" as a default over "All saves".

Comment: This is for *display*. Similarly, for adding to lists, ***a lot*** of unnecessary moves between lists could be saved this way.